# Format customer phone numbers in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

My client would like all the customer phone numbers that are entered when checking out(guest or registered user) to be unified using the (###)###-#### format.  I have found a snippet of code I believe would work but I'm not sure exactly how to implement it into the Magento form so that it executes correctly and doesn't mess up the data going into Magento when the user submits the form.  I also realize storing the numbers like this instead of 1234567890 is not best practices for many reasons, but this is what the customer wants.  Any help would be appreciated.

File I'm editing:
template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

line of code:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="billing:telephone" />
</div>
</div>
```

Code I found that I'm trying to implement:
http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=3605

```
<?php function phone_number($sPhone){ 
$sPhone = ereg_replace("[^0-9]",'',$sPhone); 
if(strlen($sPhone) != 10) return(False); 
$sArea = substr($sPhone,0,3); 
$sPrefix = substr($sPhone,3,3); 
$sNumber = substr($sPhone,6,4); 
$sPhone = "(".$sArea.")".$sPrefix."-".$sNumber; 
return($sPhone); 
} 
print phone_number("  (555) 555 - 1212 "); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validate-phoneLax class in the input field after adding this your html will look like below.

```
<input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?> validate-phoneLax" id="billing:telephone" />
```

Refresh your page, if still it doesn't work than you need to define your form,
for that add below code. and update your form id.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var myForm = new VarienForm( 'your_form_id_here' );
  </script>
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

go to prototype/validate.js and find

```
['validate-phoneStrict', 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.', function(v) {
                return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/.test(v);
            }],
```

and replace

```
  [ 'validate-phoneStrict',
      'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.',
      function(v)
      {
          return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v)
              || /\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/.test(v);
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score -2):

easy fix: just use jquery validation.js ... set your class for the field to include 'validate-phoneStrict'

using that you will be able to use the following code rule in the js:

```
'validate-phoneStrict', 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.', function(v) {
                return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/.test(v);
```